# FormMethod.Get with Html.BeginForm gives error in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core-mvc, searchbar, antiforgerytoken

I an trying to implement a *search query string* for my searchbar.

Following the [Microsoft documentation: Adding search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-search#updating-the-index-form), it suggested using `Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", FormMethod.Get)` method in view when I got the error:

> #### This page isn’t working
>
> If the problem continues, contact the site owner.
>
> <sub>HTTP ERROR 405</sub>

My search query string shows:

> localhost:7185/Searchbar__RequestVerificationToken=CfDJ8GCygMwCAINPiWbEfcvWp986TX925YtT_ivBMr4CJ0Cj6g6BDdH6xua1gReYA37rr5ljwc_GCuVXkANiQOt6hWJVJpOLr308aqLyyO6ii9fpf6DIbDlkKxYtOHHrN-O5eOxj4ie-TU-C-uBX2CNp0x4&SearchString=a&__RequestVerificationToken=CfDJ8GCygMwCAINPiWbEfcvWp986TX925YtT_ivBMr4CJ0Cj6g6BDdH6xua1gReYA37rr5ljwc_GCuVXkANiQOt6hWJVJpOLr308aqLyyO6ii9fpf6DIbDlkKxYtOHHrN-O5eOxj4ie-TU-C-uBX2CNp0x4

I have used `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` in the controller:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString)
{
    //Code
}
```

Along with `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in the view:

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Searchbar", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <form class="d-flex w-50 ps-lg-5" role="search" asp-controller="Searchbar" asp-action="Index">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control shadow-none" value="@TempData["searchString"]" type="search" placeholder="Search" id="text-suggestion" aria-label="Search" name="SearchString"
                   required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity(' ')" />
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success shadow-none" type="submit" id="search-button"><i class='bx bx-search'></i></button>
        </div>
    </form>
}
```

Comment: Your action has `[HttpPost]` but your `Html.BeginForm` has `FormMethod.Get` which will render to `<form method="get">`. Spot the difference.

Comment: Additionally, your `@Html.BeginForm` call will render a `<form>` element, but then you have a `<form>` tag-helper as a child element - which is incorrect.

Comment: @Dai Thank you for pointing that out. My code has began working after removing `[HttpPost]` and `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` from my controller.

Comment: ...so you're still (incorrectly) rendering nested `<form>` elements?

Comment: @Dai you are correct! I was rendering my _View_ incorrectly. Now I have fixed it, the _search query string_ is working perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

#### This is my Solution

---

- **Remove `[HttpPost]` from controller action.**

  - As using **FormMethod.Get** with **Html.BeginForm** will render to `<form method="get">`, you *cannot* use `[HttpPost]` in controller which renders to `<form method="post">`.

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString)
{
    //Code
}
```

- **Remove `<form>` element from View**

  - As **Html.BeginForm** renders a `<form>` element, your existing `<form>` tag-helper will behave as a *child element*.
  - Even without following this step your page will render, but this will cause the *search query string* to behave weirdly.

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Searchbar", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <div class="input-group d-flex ps-lg-5">
        <input class="form-control shadow-none" value="@TempData["searchString"]" type="search" placeholder="Search" id="text-suggestion" aria-label="Search" name="SearchString"
                required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity(' ')" />
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success shadow-none" type="submit" id="search-button"><i class='bx bx-search'></i></button>
    </div>
}
```

---

Thank you.